# ELT pipeline for Mongo

Tags: mongodb, amazon-redshift, etl

I am trying to get my data into Amazon Redshift using Fivetran, but have some questions in general about the ELT/ETL process. My source database is Mongo but I want to perform deep analysis on the data using a 3rd party BI tool like Looker, but they integrate with SQL. I am new to the ELT/ETL process and was wondering would it look like this.

1. Extract data from Mongo (handled by Fivetran)
2. Load into Amazon Redshift (handled by Fivetran)
3. Perform Transformation - This is where my biggest knowledge gap is. I obviously have to convert objects and arrays into compatible SQL types. I can perform a transformation on all objects to extract those to columns and transform all arrays to a table. Is this the right idea? Should I design a MYSQL schema and write all the transformations according to that schema design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you state, Fivetran will load your data into Redshift putting individual fields in columns where it can and putting everything else into varchar columns as JSON. So at that point you basically have a Data Lake - all your data in an analytical platform but basically still in source format and available for you to do whatever you want with it.

Initially, if you don't know much about your data and just want to investigate it, you can probably leave it as it is. Redshift has SQL functions that allow you to query the elements of a JSON structure so there is no need to build additional tables and more ETL just to allow you to investigate your data - especially as these tables may get thrown away once you understand your data and decide what you want to do with it.

If you have proper reporting requirements then that is the point where you can start to design a schema that will support these requirements (I'm not sure why you suggested a MYSQL schema as MYSQL is a database vendor?). Traditionally an analytical schema would be designed as a Kimball Dimensional model (facts and dimensions) but the type of schema you decide to design will depend on:

1. The database platform you are using (in your case, Redshift) and the type of structures it works best with e.g. star schema or "flat" tables
2. The BI tool you are using and how it expects to have data presented to it

For example (and I'm not saying this is a real world example), if Redshift works ok with star schemas but better with flat tables and Looker has to have a star schema then it probably makes more sense to build star schemas in Redshift as this is a single modelling exercise - rather than model flat tables in Redshift and then have to model star schemas in Looker.

Hope this helps?

Comment: Yep this helped. I decided to go forward with snowflake, they make it super easy to query json data with their new variant data type and flatten functions. I just use the post transformation to load json into a new flattened table.

Comment: Good decision! IMO Snowflake blows all the other cloud DBs out of the water

Comment: @joethemow am also pushing my data to snowflake from MongoDB via fivetran. 
you mentioned you used post-transformation. I want to flatten array data. If you can guide me on what you used or any blog etc, it will be helpful

Comment: Hey @JerinAMathews, Here is a simple example of how to convert array data to rows. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252105/lateral-flatten-array-with-multiple-json-objects-in-snowflake. Another tip, check out table views. Originally when I transformed my data I would create a new table but realized I ended up duplicating data, until I found out about views :)!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you need the final stage of your data analysis presented, and what the purpose of your data analysis is.  As stated by NickW, assuming you need to integrate your data into a BI tool the schema should be adapted according to the tool's data format requirements.

a [mongodb ETL/ELT process](https://rivery.io/docs/walkthrough-mongodb#) might looks like this:

*Select Connection*: Select the set connection
Collection Name:Choose the collection by using the  [database].[collection] format.
If you pulling data from your authentication database, only the [collection] name can be determined. Examples:  ea sample.products east .

**Extract Method**:

*All:* pull the entire data in the table.

*Incremental:* pull data by incremental value.

*Incremental Attributes:* Set the name of the incremental attribute to run by. I.e:  UpdateTime .

*Incremental Type:* Timestamp | Epoch. Choose the type of incremental attribute.

Choose Range:

*In Timestamp*, choose your date increment range to run by.
*In Epoch*, choose the value increment range to run by.
*If no End Date/Value entered*, the default is the last date/value in the table.
The increment will be managed automatically
Include End Value: Should the increment process take the end value or not

*Interval Chunks:* On what chunks the data will be pulled by. Split the data by minutes, hours, days, months or years.

*Filter:* Filter the data to pull. The filter format will be a  MongoDB Extended JSON.

*Limit:* Limit the rows to pull.

*Auto Mapping:* You can choose the set of columns you want to bring, add a new column or leave it as it is.

Converting Entire Key Data As a STRING
In cases the data is not as expected by a target, like key names started with numbers, or flexible and inconsistent object data,  You can convert attributes to a STRING format by setting their data types in the mapping section as STRING

Conversion exists for any value under that key.
Arrays and objects will be converted to JSON strings.

**Use cases:**
Here are few filtering examples:

```
{"account":{"$oid":"1234567890abcde"}, "datasource": "google", "is_deleted": {"$ne": true}}
```

`date(MODIFY_DATE_START_COLUMN) >=date("2020-08-01")`